# Zip new file in VB: File is being used by another procces

Tags: vb.net

Hi folks I'm trying to zip file from a path to another path using ZipArchive and ZipFile but I can't achieve it.

```
zipped = "C:\Images\zip\file01.ZIP"
file = "C:\Images\file01.BAK"

Using newFile As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipped, ZipArchiveMode.Create)
                newFile.CreateEntryFromFile(zipped, file, CompressionLevel.Optimal)
End Using
```

I'm getting the error: "C:\Images\zip\file01.ZIP" File is being used by another proccess

I will appreciate the help

Comment: Have you created "C:\Images\file01.BAK" in the same program? If so, then it looks like it hasn't been closed. Or does the error refer to the zip file?

Comment: sorry, the error refers to .zip file, not the .bak file. I will update the question

Answer (score 1):

Try archive mode `Update` instead of `Create` for a new entry in a zip archive from an existing file

```
zipped = "C:\Images\zip\file01.ZIP"
file = "C:\Images\file01.BAK"

Using newFile As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipped, ZipArchiveMode.Update)
     newFile.CreateEntryFromFile(zipped, file, CompressionLevel.Optimal)
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks a lot display name! using mode Update has resolved my problem

Comment: @JorgeEscamilla Please check and select this as an answer so I can earn extra points. Thanks! :)